# java.io.StreamCorruptedException: invalid stream header: 00000001

Tags: java, exception, file-io, multiplayer

I keep getting this get this `Exception`:

```
java.io.StreamCorruptedException: invalid stream header: 00000001
```

Server side I used this to send and receive int, works fine.

Server:

```
new DataOutputStream(player1.getOutputStream()).writeInt(P1);
```

Client:

```
dataFromServer = new DataInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
dataFromServer.readInt();
```

But when I try to send an object, like this, it gives the error.

Server:

```
new ObjectOutputStream(player2.getOutputStream()).writeObject(gameCrossword);
```

Client:

```
objectFromServer = new ObjectInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
crossword = (Crossword)objectFromServer.readObject();
```

Any help would be good. Here is me sending the crossword initially prior to game session

I changed the code to use only object streams rather than data streams, upon the advice of jtahlborn

server

```
player1 = serverSocket.accept();

serverLog.append(new Date() + ": Player 1 joined session " + sessionNo + '\n');
serverLog.append("Player 1's IP address" + player1.getInetAddress().getHostAddress() + '\n');

new ObjectOutputStream(player1.getOutputStream()).writeInt(P1);
new ObjectOutputStream(player1.getOutputStream()).writeObject(gameCrossword);

player2 = serverSocket.accept();

serverLog.append(new Date() + ": Player 2 joined session " + sessionNo + '\n');

serverLog.append("Player 2's IP address" + player2.getInetAddress().getHostAddress() + '\n');

new ObjectOutputStream(player2.getOutputStream()).writeInt(P2);
new ObjectOutputStream(player2.getOutputStream()).writeObject(gameCrossword);
```

client

```
              private void connectToServer() {

    try {
        Socket socket = new Socket(host, 8000);
        objectFromServer = new ObjectInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
        objectToServer = new ObjectOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());

    } catch (IOException ex) {
        System.err.println(ex);
    }

    Thread thread = new Thread(this);
    thread.start();
}

@Override
public void run() {

    try {
        player = objectFromServer.readInt();
        crossword = (Crossword)objectFromServer.readObject();
        System.out.println(crossword);
```

regards,
C.

Comment: You forgot to add the additional supporting code.

Comment: Are you reading the object after you are reading the int?

Comment: I am reading the object after the int, I have updated post with that code, have a look..

thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

don't wrap the socket streams with more than one input/output streams.  this will break in all kinds of bad ways.  in this specific case, the ObjectInputStream reads a header from the stream *on construction*, which is happening before you have read the int from the stream.  regardless, just use a single ObjectOutputStream and ObjectInputStream and ditch the Data streams (note that ObjectOutputStream has a `writeInt` method).

Comment: I've done this, theres no error anymore but they do not connect anymore. I will update my post with code I have tried