# AES screwing up serialization/deserialization over sockets. Invalid stream header. Java

Tags: java, sockets, serialization, stream, aes

I am working on a project where I need to encrypt java objects and send them over sockets. Serialization and deserialization works perfectly when the objects AREN'T encrypted, but when I do encrypt them I am getting:

```
Error: invalid stream header: 5F15DD25
java.io.StreamCorruptedException: invalid stream header: 5F15DD25
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readStreamHeader(ObjectInputStream.java:802)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.<init>(ObjectInputStream.java:299)
    at Utils.deserializeEnv(Utils.java:236)
    at Utils.decryptEnv(Utils.java:221)
    at GroupThread.run(GroupThread.java:59)
Exception in thread "Thread-2" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at GroupThread.run(GroupThread.java:63)
```

At an ObjectInputStream in my deserialization method. I will bold the line below.

I have my sockets like this:

```
ObjectOutputStream output = new ObjectOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
ObjectInputStream input = new ObjectInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
```

And serialize and deserialize objects like this:

```
static byte[] serializeEnv(Envelope message) {
    try {
        ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(baos);
        oos.writeObject(message);
        return baos.toByteArray();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.err.println("Error: " + e.getMessage());
        e.printStackTrace(System.err);
    }
    return null;
}

static Envelope deserializeEnv(byte[] bytes) {
    System.out.println("\nRECEVIVED LENGTH: " + bytes.length + ". SEND BYTES YO: " + bytes[0] + ", " + bytes[1] + ", " + bytes[2] + ", " + bytes[3] + ", " + bytes[4]);
    ObjectInputStream ois = null;
    try {
```

***Error here ONLY when the bytes have been encrypted/decrypted***

```
           ois = new ObjectInputStream(new ByteArrayInputStream(bytes)); // Error
           Envelope message = (Envelope) ois.readObject();
           return message;
    } catch (IOException | ClassNotFoundException e) {
        System.err.println("Error: " + e.getMessage());
        e.printStackTrace(System.err);
    }
    return null;
}
```

Here is how I encrypt and decrypt:

```
static byte[] encryptEnv(Envelope message, SecretKey secretKey) {
    try {
        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding", "BC");
        cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, secretKey);
        byte[] serializedEnv = serializeEnv(message);
        return cipher.doFinal(serializedEnv);
    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException | NoSuchProviderException | NoSuchPaddingException | InvalidKeyException e) {
        System.err.println("Error: " + e.getMessage());
        e.printStackTrace(System.err);
    } catch (IllegalBlockSizeException | BadPaddingException e) {
        System.err.println("Error: " + e.getMessage());
        e.printStackTrace(System.err);
    }
    return null;
}

static Envelope decryptEnv(int length, byte[] bytes, SecretKey secretKey, IvParameterSpec ivSpec) {
    try {
        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding", "BC");
        cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, secretKey, ivSpec);
        byte[] decrypted = cipher.doFinal(bytes);
        return deserializeEnv(decrypted);
    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException | NoSuchProviderException | NoSuchPaddingException e) {
        System.err.println("Error: " + e.getMessage());
        e.printStackTrace(System.err);
    } catch (InvalidKeyException | InvalidAlgorithmParameterException | IllegalBlockSizeException | BadPaddingException e) {
        System.err.println("Error: " + e.getMessage());
        e.printStackTrace(System.err);
    }
    return null;
}
```

To send the encrypted byte array over the socket I just add it to a wrapper class, Envelope, and send it: `output.writeObject(myEnvelope)` and retreive it `myEnvelope = (Envelope) input.readObject()`

Can anyone see how the encryption is messing everything up?

Comment: Any specific reason you are omitting the IV in encrypt method?

Comment: Check out this link:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20773657/java-io-streamcorruptedexception-invalid-stream-header-00000001

Should fix the problem. Also why are you omitting the IV?

Comment: @anttix what do you mean?

Comment: @user2494817 could you elaborate

Answer (score 0):

anttix was right, I somehow forgot to include the initialization vector in my encryption cipher. sigh.

`cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, secretKey);` -->

`cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, secretKey, ivSpec);`