# Error "java.io.StreamCorruptedException: invalid stream header: 5B424037"

Tags: java, java-io

I have a `FootballPlayer` entity class which implements the `Serializable` interface. I am saving the objects from this class to a database table using the `longblob` type.

That is working fine, but when retrieving the objects from the database, I am getting a `StreamCorruptedException`.

Here is my code:

```
public FootballPlayer searchFBPlayer(String id){

        try {

            String sql = "SELECT * FROM player";
            ResultSet rs = DBConnection.getData(sql);
            // search for player
            while (rs.next()) {
                ByteArrayInputStream bais = new ByteArrayInputStream(rs.getBytes("fbPlayer"));
                //test
                if(bais==null) System.out.println("Null BAIS");
                else System.out.println("No Null BAIS");
                //test
                FootballPlayer fbp = (FootballPlayer) toObject(bais);
                if(fbp.getPlayerID().equals(id))
                    return fbp;
            }
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }


private Object toObject(ByteArrayInputStream arr){

        ObjectInputStream ins;
        try{
        ins = new ObjectInputStream(arr);
        return ins.readObject();
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Code to save:

```
public int addFootballPlayer(FootballPlayer player){

        byte[] data=toByte(player);
        String sql="INSERT INTO footballplayer(footballPlayer) VALUES('"+data+"')";
        return DBConnection.setData(sql);
    }

private byte[] toByte(Object obj){

        try{
        ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(bos);
        oos.writeObject(obj);
        oos.flush();
        oos.close();
        bos.close();

        byte[] data = bos.toByteArray();
        return data;

        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Here is my stack trace:

```
java.io.StreamCorruptedException: invalid stream header: 5B424037
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readStreamHeader(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at com.league.database.DBAccess.toObject(DBAccess.java:67)
    at com.league.database.DBAccess.searchPlayer(DBAccess.java:34)
    at com.league.main.Test.main(Test.java:20)
```

I don't have any kind of networking in my code such as sockets. What am I doing wrong, and how can I fix this issue?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20773657/java-io-streamcorruptedexception-invalid-stream-header-00000001

Comment: How did you put your object to database? Did you use `setObject(varID,objectToSerialize)` on PreperedStatement? Consider using way described here http://javapapers.com/core-java/serialize-de-serialize-java-object-from-database/

Comment: @Pshemo I have put the code for saving

Comment: @user3112250 It looks like you are sending your bytes as String which will not put actual bytes for your array but will use result of `toString()` method on byte array which will generate something like `[B@1db9742`. Try printing your `sql` string you are trying to execute and you will see what I mean. Consider reading tutorial I linked in my previous comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is the point where you create the SQL. You should be using a PreparedStatement at this point, and passing the data as an argument: not converting the data to String.